# Mutt: don't ask for pgp passphrase

Tags: gpg, mutt

I have a gpg key without password. In mutt I set the config to sign all the messages. But every time I send a message "Enter PGP passphrase". How can I get rid of it. Here is the config for the command:

```
set pgp_sign_command="gpg --no-verbose --batch --output - --passphrase-fd 0 --armor --detach-sign --textmode %?a?-u %a? %f"
```

Comment: Is `set pgp_default_key` or `set pgp_sign_as` defined in your .muttrc file ? What is your version of GnuPG ?

Comment: @Anonymous No, they are not defined. How to define them for an empty key? gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.23

Comment: I have a couple ideas, but does Mutt send the message as expected if you enter a blank passphrase ?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to sign messages but not encrypt them you would need to set this option: `pgp_default_key` or: `pgp_sign_as`.

From the [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#encryption):

> 9.1. OpenPGP Configuration
>
> The two most important settings are $pgp_default_key and $pgp_sign_as.
>   To perform encryption, you must set the first variable. If you have a
>   separate signing key, or only have a signing key, then set the second.
>   Most people will only need to set $pgp_default_key.

Also note this remark regarding version of GnuPG:

> Starting with version 2.1.0, GnuPG automatically uses an agent to
>   prompt for your passphrase. If you are using a version older than
>   that, you'll need to ensure an agent is running (alternatively, you
>   can unset $pgp_use_gpg_agent and Mutt will prompt you for your
>   passphrase). The agent in turn uses a pinentry program to display the
>   prompt. There are many different kinds of pinentry programs that can
>   be used: qt, gtk2, gnome3, fltk, and curses. However, Mutt does not
>   work properly with the tty pinentry program. Please ensure you have
>   one of the GUI or curses pinentry programs installed and configured to
>   be the default for your system.
>   ...

The repeated prompt for passphrase makes me thing GPG agent is lacking.
In your case, I'd check the version of Gnupg and preferably use Gnupg2.
It's possible both are already installed on your system but v1 is still default, check with `gpg --version`.